# How to make a line look like the CSS border-bottom dotted 1 px in svg?

Tags: css, svg

I am trying to create a dotted line that looks like

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted #ddd;
```

However, I'm not getting that result.  It keeps looking a bit big or the color is too faded.

```
  stroke: #ddd;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 1 ,2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
```

Is there a better way to do this than SVG Line?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the dasharray. It should be `stroke-dasharray: 0,2`, not `1,2`. See http://jsfiddle.net/cMHLt/1/

Also a 10x scaled up version: http://jsfiddle.net/aXuLF/1/

**Some explanation:**
The linecap is drawn around the extremities of the path ([illustrated here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes#Stroke)). If you have a `round` linecap you will have one half-circle at one end and the other at the opposing end. To end up with just a circle you must not have anything between the ends, this means a 0-width solid segment in the dasharray.

Comment: It appears there is an issue with chrome.  I saw your example and I thought it was wrong for a second until I tested it in firefox.  Its a bit buggy.